# Понятие методической проблемы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли к методическим проблемам при освоении какой-либо области знаний отнести несовершенства памяти, особенности ее функционирования?

Например: "необходимость повторения - методическая проблема" - допустимо ли так выразиться?

Comment: Исправил, "методическая"

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что нет. Методическая проблема определяется не как *наличие препятствия* (которое принципиально существует), а как задача нахождения способа его преодоления. Это проблема *поиска метода* решения. Например, методическая *проблема уменьшения количества повторений*, требуемых для усвоения материала.